# How to include "Bookman Old Style" font as a main font in my Ph.D thesis?

Tags: fonts

I am unable to figure out simple solution to add "Bookman Old Style"  as a main font in my latex document. I have used below line but does not give me required font.

```
\usepackage{bookman}
```

Could not find any Simple correct answer for this. Pl. suggest how to do it.

I am using windows, pdflatex.

thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: 'Does not give me the required font' is a bit tricky to interpret. With a simple demo `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{bookman}\begin{document}Hello world\end{document}` I do get Bookman in my PDF: what are you seeing?

Comment: Perhaps you mean Monotype's Bookman Old Style?

Comment: It could well be possible that your thesis template (I've seen these in the form of `.cls`, `.sty` and even `.tex`) could be imposing another font later.  So you could try putting `\usepackage{bookman}` *immediately before* `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 5):

The `Bookman` font does not need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX at all, it can be used with LaTeX/PdfLaTeX of course.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}
\Large
\chapter{Bookman font test}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

A look into the log or on the output screen during a compilation run shows whether the fonts are included:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Plus, there's TeX Gyre Bonum.

Comment: @Manuel, that's true -- I forget to mention

Answer (score 3):

One way to obtain the desired result is to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as follows:

1. Use package  `\usepackage{fontspec}`
2. Font:  `\setmainfont{Bookman Old Style}`
   Bookman comes in word as Bookman Old Style.

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Bookman Old Style}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Working Capital Assessment}
Banks assess the working capital needs of the borrowers in two ways. 
\section{Under Nayak Committee}
This is based on turnover. Every year the borrower has to advise his plan of action and the approximate turnover/sales he expects to achieve in the coming year. This must be supported by the projected balance sheet and profit and loss statements for the coming year. The projection of turnover/sales must be in consistent with the turnover he achieved in the previous years. The borrower is  eligible to get 20\% of  total projected turnover.  This may lead the borrowers to project a  high turnover so as to get more funds from banks in the form of working capital facility. Just to arrest the over ambitious projection  he is required to bring in  a margin equivalent to 5\% of total turnover(sales) projected. Based on the project balance sheet the banker will calculated the projected Net Working Capital. If the projected NWC is more than the required marign of 5\% of total projected turnover  the difference will be treated as excess liquidity in the hands of the borrower. So the bank will deduct the excess liquidity from the borrower's eligible working capital bank finance. Thus the maximum permissible bank finance is calculated as shown below.

\end{document}
```

[image: bookman]

Comment: I question whether you in fact _have_ to use LuaLaTeX in order to get Bookman Old Style. I am sure there are other ways although it certainly is one nice way.

Comment: If you use pdflatex you will get the following error.  "You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex"."

Comment: If you use `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont` commands, this is no wonder, why there is an error message. They are designed for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, not for `(pdf)latex`

Comment: Yes! \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Bookman Old Style}  worked using xelatex. Earlier I tried it, but the problem was  not used just before \begin{document} and got re initialized thru' some other sty file. thanks a lot for the clear and simple suggestion.

Comment: The problem is solved using xelatex. Just curious to know why \usepackage{fontspec} cannot work in latex. or any other solution is there using latex?

Comment: @Narendrababu.C: `fontspec` is designed **only** for `xelatex` or `lualatex`, not for *usual* latex/pdflatex. If you have to stick to (pdf)latex, try the way I have shown in my answer